# C++ Convert int to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, int, wchar-t

So I've been trying to convert integer values to wchar_t*. This is the test I run so I could simplify it as much as I can.

```
int test=123;
wchar_t *testc[12][12];testc[0][0]=L"hello";
_itow(test,testc[0][0],10);
wcout<<testc[0][0];
```

This code right here compiles but also gives me the Not Responding error of doom.
What is VERY strange for my understanding is why this

```
int test=123;
wchar_t *testc[12][12];testc[0][0]=L"hello";
_itow(test,testc[1][0],10);
wcout<<testc[0][0]<<testc[1][0];
```

Works without any problem, and showing the output "hello123" just as intended.

Any idea why this happens?

My project has some occurrences similar to the first code shown (except the wcout part), thus I want to understand why they give me the Not Responding state.

Comment: I don't think either will compile. At least it doesn't compile [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd134871fa6a6269). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `testc` is just a set of pointers, but they don't point anywhere. So there is no place to store the result of the conversion. You could try [`std::to_wstring(test)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) instead and skip the pointers.

Comment: your testc[1][0] is not pointing anywhere that could be problem for second case

Comment: Side note: Never let a non-const pointer point to a string literal – which essentially is what `testc[0][0]=L"hello";` is doing. That literal resides in read-only memory. As soon as you attempt to write to it through `testc` you’ll get undefined behaviour: probably a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue with your code is not allocating memory for testc[1][0].
Also it will be better to use standard c++ functions like std::to_wstring instead of _itow.

So here is sample code for your problem :

```
int main()
{
  int test=123;
  wchar_t *testc[12][12];
  testc[0][0]=L"hello";
  testc[1][0] = new wchar_t[4];
  std::wstring temp  = std::to_wstring(123);
  for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
  {
      testc[1][0][i] = temp[i];
  }
  wcout<<testc[0][0]<<testc[1][0];    
  return 0;
}
```

This is just sample code and i am assuming in your program you are taking care of memory allocation and deallocation